# how to write the select statement in case statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, temp-tables

Let me know how to write select query in case statement.

```
select
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by vendor.VendorName ) AS ID,
PH.PurchasingHeaderID as BILLNo,
PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency as Balance,
acc.AccountName as [Account_Name]  
**Into #tempOpenVedorlist** 
from PurchasingHeader PH
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionType Trans ON PH.TransactionTypeID =Trans.TransactionTypeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor vendor on PH.VendorID=vendor.VendorID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PaymentTerm PT on PT.PaymentTermID = vendor.PaymentTermID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchasingDetail PD on PD.PurchasingHeaderID = PH.PurchasingHeaderI
LEFT OUTER JOIN Account Acc on Acc.AccountID= PD.FinancialAccountID 
where PH.TransactionTypeID=7
Group by vendor.VendorName,
PH.PurchasingHeaderID,PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency,acc.AccountName
```

I GOT THIS RESULT :

with this result:  Here i have No : VB1003 two times but Account Name is different.

```
ID      BILLNo          Account_Name            Balance   
-------------------------------------------------------------
 101      VB1000        Cash-Petty Cash         4000.00  
 102     VB1001        Accounts Receivable      5000.00 
 103    VB1003       Cash-PettyCash             6000.00 
 104     VB1003       Cash                      6000.00  
 105    VB1004        UndepositedFunds          7000.00
```

Here i have to show ;

I need this result :

```
ID      BILLNo        Account_Name          Balance    
------------------------------------------------------
 101      VB1000      Cash-PettyCash        4000.00  
 102      VB1001      AccountsReceivable     5000.00  
 103     VB1003      ---Multiple----        6000.00  
 104     VB1004      UndepositedFunds      7000.00
```

For aboue result what i have did : i have taken all the data in temp table.

Am able show Multiple string for which has more than one No.

But unfortunatly am not able show Account Name for which has only one BILLNo.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by BILLNo ) AS ID,
[BILLNo],
Balance,
 CASE
 WHEN count(BILLNo)>1 THEN 'Multipul'
 WHEN count(BILLNo)<2 THEN **(Select Account_Name from #tempOpenVedorlist )** 
 End As [Financial_Account] 
from #tempOpenVedorlist
Group By BILLNo,Balance
```

Let me know how can i get account name from temp table which is related to that BILLNo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `AccountName` from the `GROUP BY` and put an aggregate on that.

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by vendor.VendorName ) AS ID,
        PH.PurchasingHeaderID as BILLNo,
        PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency as Balance,
        CASE WHEN MIN(acc.AccountName) IS NULL
             THEN '----'
             WHEN MIN(acc.AccountName) = MAX(acc.AccountName)
             THEN MIN(acc.AccountName) 
             ELSE '--MULTIPLE--' 
        END  as [Account_Name]  
INTO    #tempOpenVedorlist
FROM    PurchasingHeader PH
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionType Trans 
            ON PH.TransactionTypeID =Trans.TransactionTypeID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor vendor 
            ON PH.VendorID=vendor.VendorID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PaymentTerm PT 
            ON PT.PaymentTermID = vendor.PaymentTermID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchasingDetail PD 
            ON PD.PurchasingHeaderID = PH.PurchasingHeaderI
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Account Acc 
            ON Acc.AccountID= PD.FinancialAccountID 
WHERE   PH.TransactionTypeID=7
GROUP BY  vendor.VendorName,
        PH.PurchasingHeaderID,
        PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency
```

Comment: If i remove the account Name from Group by , i am getting error like :Column 'Account.AccountName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I think you'll need a `MIN()` in the `THEN` since there are still potentially multiple rows at that point.

Comment: Check now please. I enclosed all in a MAX, so it should work.

Comment: `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.` so I switched it to my suggestion instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, jyparask Thank for your reply.what if account name as null. i need to show null value which BillNo has empty account name

Comment: i have used this case statemtn : CASE 
             WHEN MIN(acc.AccountName) = MAX(acc.AccountName)
             THEN MIN(acc.AccountName) ---single 
             WHEN MIN(acc.AccountName) > MAX(acc.AccountName)
             THEN '--- MULTIPLE --' ---Multiple
             ELSE '----'  --Null Account
             
        END  as [Account_Name]

Comment: using aboue case statement i am getting not getting empty(---)for account name which does not have account name.(Means alwyes am getting --Multiple-- except for single BillNo

Comment: @Havab You should probably check `first` for null and then the rest.